# How to tell an Applescript to stop executing

Tags: applescript

Applescript's "choose from list" user interaction has a "cancel" button — I want this "cancel" to tell the script to immediately stop executing. In other words:

```
 set wmColor to choose from list {"Black", "Black for all", "White", 
     "White for all"} with prompt "What color should the watermark be?" 
     default items "White for all" without multiple selections allowed and 
     empty selection allowed
 if wmColor is false
     *tell script to stop executing*
 end if
```

Can't seem to find how to do this — does anyone know how?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Error number -128 is "User Cancelled", and will stop the script - for example:

```
if wmColor is false then
    error number -128
end if
```

Comment: This only works if the isn't included in a try block that catches such errors.

Comment: JXA variant: `const e = new Error("User canceled."); e.errorNumber = -128; throw e;`. Magic: the JS `Error` class does not define an `errorNumber` property, but you have to set `errorNumber` to `-128` to avoid showing the user an error dialog.

Answer (score 17):

"return" tells a script to stop executing:

```
display dialog "Do you want to exit this script?" with icon note buttons {"Exit", "Continue"}
if the button returned of the result is "Exit" then
  return
end if
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: In my opinion to stop execution of a script in a normal fashion it is the **much better** option to use `return` than to throw a user exception.

Comment: Well, not really - it tells the current handler to return (with no value). If you're at the top level of your script, that's fine, it'll end execution, but if you're in a handler it'll return a nil to whatever called it and the script will cheerfully continue executing (with possibly unexpected results if the caller isn't expecting a missing value).

Comment: This only ended an `if` statement when I used it, rather than exiting the script.  The `error` method is better.

Comment: I would just change this code so it is one line: `if wmColor is false then return`

Answer (score 4):

For the specific case of an AppleScript invoked via osascript, it can be terminated, returning a status of 0 to the shell, by doing:

```
tell me to "exit"
```

Terminate, emitting a message and returning a status of 1, by doing:

```
tell me to error "{your message}"
```

The above writes a line like this to standard error:

```
{scriptname}: execution error: {your message} (-2700)
```

Here is an example that replaces the cryptic "-2700" and likely does what jefflovejapan is looking for:

```
tell me to error "Terminated by user" number 0
```

which writes this to standard error:

```
{scriptname}: execution error: Terminated by user (0)
```

and returns a status of 1.

I learned this by experiment, after reading:
[AppleScript Language Guide - error Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657)

Answer (score 2):

I found this works well for scripts running within an application (for example, InDesign CS5.5):

```
repeat 100 times
    tell application ("System Events") to keystroke "." using command down
    delay (random number from 0.5 to 5)
end repeat
```

This was modified from this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/36947/115223).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the word "quit" to quit the current application. You can use this if you save your script as an application.

```
if wmColor is false
    quit
end if
```

Comment: Just note that if you use the quit command on a script running inside Script Editor, it will quit the Script Editor.

Comment: "quit" doesn't work if you're in a tell application "Finder" block.

Comment: It's quitting the automator on run and display error `Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.` in the terminal while using this.