# Why doesn't my AppleScript quit when I click Cancel in a dialog?

Tags: applescript

I have this line in an AppleScript

```
set theResponse to display dialog "Name?" default answer myname with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"
```

If I click cancel the script continues. I want it to quit.

However, if I click cancel in this dialog:

```
display dialog "cancel"
```

the execution is interrupted.

- Both lines are at the "root" level, that is, no `try`, `if` or similar clause.
- I am not using English as my system language.
- I have read this question [How to tell an Applescript to stop executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621290/how-to-tell-an-applescript-to-stop-executing) but the solutions there didn't seem applicable for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cancel` button is localized. It works if you use the name in your system language.

You can specify an explicit `cancel button` in `display dialog` which works in any localization

```
set theResponse to display dialog "Name?" default answer myname with icon note buttons {"Quit", "Continue"} cancel button "Quit" default button "Continue"
```

If you click `Quit` the button behaves like the standard `Cancel` button. It throws error -128 which is *User cancelled*